# Adding multiple UIButtons to an UIView with a selector action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolevents, addtarget

I've added some buttons to an UIView (via addSubview) programmatically. I’ve added to this button an @selector with a function. However, they appear in the view but when I do click,  the last button works only.

Into my .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton * myButton;
```

Into my .m

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(55, 55*i, 30, 30);
myButton.tag = i;
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:myButton];

}

-(void)myaction:(UIButton *)sender{
  if(sender.tag == 0){
    NSLog(@“uibutton clicked %ld", (long)sender.tag);
  }
}
```

How do I add the action to all buttons? not for the last only...

Comment: You are overwriting each time the same var?

Comment: So what's your issue then? Do you see all 5 buttons? Is `myaction` called for all 5 buttons? It should be based on the code you posted.

Comment: I can see all 5 buttons, but only when I click on the button number 5 it is called. Isn't called when I click on others buttons

Comment: There must be more going on than you are showing. One obvious bit of confusion, as Larme mentioned, is your strange use of the `myButton` property. Why do you have a single button property being used to create 5 buttons? Just use a local variable and get rid of that property.

Comment: show the whole code, there must be something interfering with the buttons

Comment: I tried this too @rmaddy , but is indiferent the use of UIButton *mybutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  into the loop to declare the uibutton all times

Comment: Can you post real code?  What you have doesn't compile.  (e.g. Your use of `myButton` doesn't reference the property, `myButton = CGRectMake(55, 55*i, 30, 30)` doesn't make any sense, ....)

Comment: After fixing the errors I mentioned above, your code works fine for me.  (Even better after deleting `if(sender.tag == 0){`.)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(55, 55*i, 30, 30);
        myButton.tag = i;
        myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    }


}

-(void)myaction:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"uibutton clicked %ld", (long)sender.tag);
}
```

The code you posted in your question appears to be *"this is what my code looks like"* rather than your actual code. That can cause problems when people try to help.

In the future, post your actual code.

Comment: This is the same code (other than the button title) in the question. How does this solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Let's make it more dynamic by calculating the height of the button and adding padding based on the number of buttons.

:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSInteger height = self.frame.size.height - 5*20; // 5 is the button count 
 and 20 is the padding 
 NSInteger buttonHeight = height/5;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(55, buttonHeight*i+padding*(i+1), 150, 
     buttonHeight);
    myButton.tag = i;
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}}

-(void)myaction:(UIButton *)sender{
 NSLog(@"uibutton clicked %ld", (long)sender.tag);
}
```

You could make it more dynamic by calculating the height of the button like this:

```
NSInteger height = self.frame.size.height - 5*20; 
NSInteger buttonHeight = height/5;
```

Comment: Please don't post code without any explanation. A good answer explains what was wrong and how the answer solves the issue.